# Can't clean-install printer on Windows. No obvious error. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: windows-8.1, installation, printing, vmware-workstation, network-printer

I'm running Windows 8.1 x64 inside VMWare Workstation Pro 15.1. The VM works smoothly, and hasn't ever had issues. I'm trying to reinstall my (Ethernet wired) HP printer on it, after a printer IP change. It finds the printer on the LAN, tries to install it, but after a long time reports it couldn't install it.  It does that for both HP's own Printer Installer (which I've used for ages on all LAN devices and is the latest) and with Windows "Add Printer".

Things tried:

- Reboot VM
- Update VMWare Tools, confirm Windows Updates all up to date, and reboot again
- Open Printer control panel, run "Server Properties" as admin, delete all drivers and software for the printer (I ran as administrator, and deleted both drivers and software)
- Confirm the VM's host machine can print to the printer and doesn't have an issue.
- Restart Spooler service
- Microsoft's print troubleshooter ("Find and fix printer problems") with admin enabled and repair=yes. It sits on "checking for spooler errors" and seems to never finish. As a second test, I stopped the spooler service in Task Manager, and reran the printer troubleshooter; it was unable to restart the service and sat there indefinitely too (see screenshots).
- Tried `sfc /scannow`. Nothing found.
- Checked with another VM (same OS version, running on same VMWare install on the same host). On the other VM, Printer Troubleshooter does restart the spooler, and printer is added correctly.
- Rechecked Server Properties panel. The printer driver isn't showing up in it.

So it's not a host or hypervisor issue, its an OS problem somewhere in the Windows 8.1 VM. It looks like something's fundamentally borked, but I still can't tell what, or how to fix it. The screenshots are below, but are pretty unhelpful.

I've never seen this before. Where do I go from here?

## Screenshots:

**Printers found on LAN:**

[image]

**Windows Add Printer error:**

[image]

**HP Printer Installer error:**

[image]

**Printer troubleshooter, after 4 hours running:**

[image]

**Printer troubleshooter (as admin) also unable to turn on spooler after 20-30 mins, although I can do so manually in Task Manager so the service does seem to be working:**

[image]

**SFC output:**

[image]

**Drivers and devices currently recognised (see comment by @Ramhound):**

[image]

Comment: When you uninstall the printer through Device Manager, did you choose the option, that removes the .inf file entirely?

Comment: which network option are you using, bridged or NAT?

Comment: @Ramhound - yes (I didn't use dev manager, I used the printers -> server properties panel but removed drivers and sw).

Comment: @essjae - bridged.